# Change WCF service type

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have created simple console web service application.

```
namespace WCF_con
{

    [ServiceContract]
    interface IStringService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Reverse(string s);
    }

    class MyStringService : IStringService
    {
        public string Reverse(string s)
        {
            return new string(s.Reverse().ToArray());
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {


        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
            binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;

            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/StringService");

            using (ServiceHost serviceHost =
                new ServiceHost(typeof (MyStringService), baseAddress))
            {
                // Check to see if it already has a ServiceMetadataBehavior
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb =
                    serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb == null)
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();

                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy12;
                serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                // Add MEX endpoint
                serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
                    ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
                    MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
                    "mex"
                    );

                serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (IStringService), binding, baseAddress);



                serviceHost.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("The service is running. Press any key to stop.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to Charles it's function call is of type SOAP :

```
POST /StringService HTTP/1.1
Cache-Control   no-cache
Pragma  no-cache
Content-Type    application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
User-Agent  MS-WebServices/1.0
Content-Length  456
Host    10.1.2.222:8000
```

Now I need to create WCF service application that must be the same type like console application web service. After doing File->new-->Project->WCF Service Application I got simple web service and according to Charles its function call is of type described below :

```
POST /Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type    text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction  "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData"
Host    10.1.2.222:8733
Content-Length  158
Expect  100-continue
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
```

How to adjust WCF Service Application to be the same type like console service application?

Comment: You need to have them in seperate projects. 1 for the host, 1 for the client and 1 as the WCFService Library.

Comment: _"How to adjust WCF Service Application to be the same type like console service application?"_ - by copying the relevant `system.serviceModel` configuration sections.

Comment: where is system.serviceModel?

Comment: In your application configuration. You seem to configure your console service from code though, so you'll have to configure your second application with a `WSHttpBinding`.

Comment: I suppose, i need to edit .config file. Must I edit it manually or there are any configurators? If manually, how to know what are possible values?